# How to move title bar buttons to the left in Pantheon/Gala?

Tags: window-buttons, titlebar, pantheon

I want to move the window-buttons to the left in the Pantheon 1.29.

How can I do this?

Comment: Pantheon is the shell, the Window Manager is called Gala.

Comment: @UriHerrera I am aware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to install `dconf-editor`.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Open `dconf` and navigate to:  `org -> pantheon -> desktop -> gala -> appearance`

Change `button-layout` from `close:maximize` to `close,minimize:maximize` or `close,minimize,maximize:` depending on whether or not to want to keep the maximize button on the right.

[image]

If you want to move the buttons to the *right*, like in Gnome or KDE, change the value of `button-layout` to `:maximize,minimize,close`

[image]

Comment: Exactly. It's basically what we've been doing for years on the Good Old Gnome 2, but in a new key.